# Get site url(s) that wsp is deployed to

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Is it possible to get a list of sites that a given .wsp is deployed to? For my uninstall script I need to retract and remove certain wsps that have been deployed, but I do not know the exact url that they have been deployed to.

Current Script:

```
uninstall-spsolution -identity mysolution.wsp -webapplication $url -confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Get-SPSolution cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607754(v=office.15).aspx) for that purpose.

The following script returns the list of web applications (url property) where a given package is deployed to:

```
$solution = Get-SPSolution -Identity $solutionName 
$solution.DeployedWebApplications | Format-Table -Property Url
```